# Handling Device error with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, authentication, devise

I'm using rails 3 and Devise and i'm trying to restrict some actions to ed in users. REST calls in my application are done using JSON.

When i have to be logged in, Device returns this:
`{
    "email": "",
    "password": ""
}`

How can i change this message to contain a custom JSON message ?

NOTE: i'm protecting my controllers using: `before_filter authenticate_user!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1361